# Github: How to solve hanging pull request?

Tags: github, pull-request

My [repo](https://github.com/WeeSee/yii2-usuario) is a fork from upstream repo [2amigos/yii2-usuario](https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-usuario).

My repo is behind some commits. I want to re-sync all commit and created a pull request by switching the base, so that the upstream repo gets merged into my repo.

While [creating the pull request](https://github.com/WeeSee/yii2-usuario/pull/1), Github says

```
Able to merge. These branches can be automatically merged.
```

But, when the pull request is created, Github just [shows](https://github.com/WeeSee/yii2-usuario/pull/1)

```
Checking for ability to merge automatically…
Hang in there while we check the branch’s status.
```

I cannot perform any action, neither kill the pull request nor solve it.
What should I do?

Comment: You may be able to add another commit one of the two branches (if it really hangs a long time) in order to restart the process.

Comment: Btw, I don't see where ir is displaying `Hang in there while we check the branch’s status`. Have you refreshed the page?

Comment: And...I think you should edit the PR description and answer the questions...

Comment: It happens when the commit size is big.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found it. My Safari browser didn't update the pull request state although reloading the page multiple times. Had to logout from Github and login again. Then the pull request was merge-able.

Comment: It didn't work for me unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

```
Checking for ability to merge automatically…" 
Hang in there while we check the branch’s status.
```

This was a server issue for me.
The GitHub server had not enough space to index properly etc. It was at 95% capacity. Raising the capacity of the github server solves the issue

Answer (score 0):

Similar situation with a large commit, but in Chrome, with Github showing "Able to merge. These branches can be automatically merged" and not leading to a "merge" button. Page refreshes did not resolve it. Logging out and logging into Github again resolved it: now got a "merge" button and merge worked.